# Switching between Configuration languages in ScintillaNet?

Tags: c#, lexical-analysis, scintilla

We're trying to implement an editor for a mix between javascript and HTML based on ScintillaNet.

The javascript code is embedded in between `<SCRIPT> </SCRIPT>` tags...

What I'd like to do is to be able to switch between the html and javascript configurations. Is this possible ? (I've seen the StyleNeeded event but I'm sure that this is the right event to catch)...